# How to save tensor with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, object-detection, feature-extraction

I need to save tensor by transform the x[-1] to numpy matrix, and then save it as a pkl file.

```
def forward(self, x):
        
   x=self.forward_features(x)
```

What does x[-1] means ? How can I transform x to numpy ..

```
Y=[]
Y=x.transform()
With open('result.pkl','w') as file
     Pickle.dump(Y,file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x[-1]` gets you the last item on the list.

If `x` is a list, do `np.array(x)` to convert the list to a numpy array.

To save `x` to a pickle file, do

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])

with open('res.pkl', 'wb') as df_file:
    pickle.dump(obj={'x':x}, file = df_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying and help .. but how can I transform the last element only into numpy

Comment: np.array(x[-1])

Comment: Thanks a lot .. does this logic I mean transform the last element and save it in the file will save the features ?

Comment: If the last element of your object contains the features, then yes. It is hard to say for sure with the given information, however.